# Creating a QR code using Excel Visual Basic for Applications

Tags: excel, vba, qr-code

I was asked to troubleshoot a customer's Excel file because the QR codes weren't working.

It's a .xlsm (macro enabled) file, which pulls data out of a database and puts it into the spreadsheet. On the right of each set of data is supposed to be a QR code.

I found the VBA code was trying to call

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=80x80&chl=
```

The cause was a temporary outage of Google Charts API. Google was supposed to have shut this down five years ago.

Per [the Google Charts page](https://developers.google.com/chart/image),

> This API is deprecated in 2012 and was turned off on March 18, 2019. Please use the actively maintained Google Charts API instead.

and

> While the dynamic and interactive Google Charts are actively maintained, we officially deprecated the static Google Image Charts way back in 2012. This gives us the right to turn it off without notice, which may happen soon.

Every suggestion I found for creating a QR code using a URL links to Google Charts.

I'm looking for a suggestion for this customer to implement in their VBA code once Google Charts is turned off *as they said it would be five years ago*.

It looks like current APIs for both Google Charts and things like QR code generator sites are JavaScript code meant to run in a web browser, which you can't do inside an Excel file.

Is there any other service to send a URL request to and get an image back with your QR? I'm sure it wouldn't be too difficult to write and have it hosted on GitHub, and may already be, I just can't find it with some cursory searches.

Comment: Maybe a .Net solution you could  develop a custom type library for generating and/or reading QR codes for what you require.  Not sure which is the recommended library to utilize.  Creating a type library in C# .Net Framework is "relatively easy".  The advantage can use it off-line etc.  [54 packages returned for Tags:"qrcode"](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22qrcode%22&frameworks=netframework&prerel=true&sortby=relevance)

Comment: Review https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/qrcode-image-generator.299675/#post-1894511